# Change GUC parameter before subquery PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, pg-trgm

I'm currently doing a query like such:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    (SELECT * from A WHERE first_name % 'fakeFirstName') 
    UNION 
    (SELECT * from B WHERE last_name % 'fakeLastName')
) AS result;
```

Both A and B are views of the same underlying table C, with the exact same columns.

However the `%` operator uses the GUC parameter `pg_trgm.similarity_threshold` to compute both `first_name % 'fakeFirstName'` and `last_name % 'fakeLastName'`, and my goal is to change this parameter before each sub query since the similarity thresholds are different for these two column.

To change the `pg_trgm.similarity_threshold` parameter, for example at the value 0.2, I have two options:

- `SET pg_trgm.similarity_threshold = 0.2;`
- `SELECT set_limit(0.2);`

I am very concerned with speed of execution, which means I'd prefer to use the `%` operation with a GIN index instead of the `<->` operator with a GIST index.

I tried to do something like the following, but it didn't work since the function `set_limit()` wasn't called before the use of the `%` operator:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    (SELECT *, set_limit(0.2) from A WHERE first_name % 'fakeFirstName') 
    UNION 
    (SELECT *, set_limit(0.6) from B WHERE last_name % 'fakeLastName')
) AS result;
```

Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: Thank you for your edit a_horse_with_no_name, i'm not used to posting on stackoverflow !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure, if I understand you correctly, but you can try joining A and B against CTE with `set_limit()`, eg:

```
t=# with a as (select set_limit(0.21))
, b as (select set_limit(0.22))
select show_limit(), 'a' from pg_database where datname = 't'
union
select show_limit(), 'b' from pg_database join a on true where datname = 't'
union
select show_limit(), 'c' from pg_database join b on true where datname = 't'
t-# order by 2;
 show_limit | ?column?
------------+----------
        0.2 | a
       0.21 | b
       0.22 | c
(3 rows)
```

also mind you don't change it back, so the value remains the last called `set_limit()`

Comment: Thank you very much ! Using `WITH` and `JOIN` for each subquery, i was able to set different thresholds for each of them !