# Having the GiST indexes being exploited with different thresholds on different indexes

Tags: postgresql, indexing, full-text-search

Postgresql FTS / GiST index usage question.

Let's start saying that the global value for `pg_trgm.similarity_threshold` is **0.9**:

```sql
SHOW pg_trgm.similarity_threshold;

pg_trgm.similarity_threshold|
----------------------------+
0.9                         |
```

I have those two sample tables:

###### table `t1`

| id | description |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | <some text> |
| 2 | ... |

###### table `t2`

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | <some other text> |
| 2 | ... |

Both `t1#description` and `t2#name` are `text` columns with their own GIST index:

```sql
CREATE INDEX gist_index_t1 ON t1 USING gist (description gist_trgm_ops);
CREATE INDEX gist_index_t1 ON t2 USING gist (name gist_trgm_ops);
```

If the similarity query performed agains both of them is the same and the threshold is for both the same of the global threshold (0.9), the index is used.

What if I have the need of performing a similarity query against `t2`, but with a different threshold?

###### Query 1

```sql
SELECT *
FROM t1
WHERE strict_word_similarity('a text', description) > 0.9
```

###### Query 2

```sql
SELECT *
FROM t2
WHERE strict_word_similarity('a text', name) > 0.6
```

Being the `pg_trgm.similarity_threshold` a global parameter, the GIST index will only be used on the first query.

How can I achieve this, making the two GIST indexes being used both on query 1 and query 2?

Comment: change the threshold before making the queries

Comment: So you are suggesting me to:
```sql
SET pg_trgm.similarity_threshold = 0.6;
```
before executing the query?

Will this statement be valid global-wise or in the current session only?
I'm concerning about parallel queries running both q1 and q2...

Comment: I answered myself about my last question: it will affect only the current session.

Comment: as far as i understand the manual it will be the session, but you need to test it

Answer (score 1):

That can't work with your example in any case, because you need to use an operator, not a function, to get index usage in pg_trgm.  Also, the operation you are doing would not use the threshold you are setting, because that threshold belongs to a different thing.

There is no provision to attach different thresholds like that.  You would need to change the threshold value between running the queries.  If you package the queries into function calls, you could arrange for it to happen automatically.   But you still wouldn't be able to use different thresholds at different sites within the same query.

There was [a proposal](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/CAA6WWt834QH-f20okyv6repnHm5oqe-16z0GAdiH4RzPBf9t%2BA%40mail.gmail.com) to relax this case by making a variant of the operators which accept both the target string and the threshold bundled into on composite type, but I don't think that proposal ever went anywhere.  Also, it wouldn't do what you ask for as then the threshold would be attached to a specific call site in the query text, not to the index.

Comment: It seems possible to use 2 thresholds within a single query: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49941564/change-guc-parameter-before-subquery-postgresql

Comment: @JGH Wow that looks impressive but fragile. I don't know from looking at it when each change would kick in, or whether the sequence might change from version to version or just with unpredictable changes in plan structure due to adding other joins/conditions.